# Swift: Text of Mixed Styles

Tags: swift, text, uitextview

How would I best

**format text**

of programmatically loaded text

like this, using

*differing styles* in a Swift app,

preferably **within** a *single* string?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look over [`NSAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/index.html) and it's mutable version [`NSMutableAttributedString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/index.html) class.

Also see this [tutorial](http://makeapppie.com/2014/10/20/swift-swift-using-attributed-strings-in-swift/)